# What does the order of a permutation say about it's cycle lengths?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Say we have a Permutation $a$ of $S_5$.

We know that a is of order 6. Since the order is the least common multiple of a permutation, $a$ probably looks something like this:

$(a_1, a_2, a_3)(a_4, a_5)$

My question is whether you can always determine the length of the disjunct cycle when you only have the order and the number of elements i.e. 5.

Comment: What if $a \in S_{6}$ had order 6?

Comment: Hmm, well I guess than there is no way to know how the cycles look.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The lcm of the lengths of the cycles in its cycle decomposition is equal to the order.  That's about all you can say.

Comment: So you are saying, you can't always determine the length of the cycles from it's order and number of elements?

Comment: Right.  Counterexamples shouldn't be too hard to come by.  For instance, in $S_6$, how about $(123456)$ and $(123)(45)$.